# Creating a WordListObject class for Luis In Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to implement [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-language-luis/azure.cognitiveservices.language.luis.authoring.operations.modeloperations?view=azure-python#add-closed-list-app-id--version-id--sub-lists-none--name-none--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) function into my Program, 
It takes in an Object of the class "WordListObject class", Which is inherited from the [Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/msrest/msrest.serialization.model?view=azure-python) class as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-language-luis/azure.cognitiveservices.language.luis.authoring.models.wordlistobject?view=azure-python), which I am trying to create.

I have already tried creating the same object using a Dict, which gave me "Unable to Serialize"
I also trying to create a class of Model and use "from_dict" function which also failed.

The patch_closed_list() function takes in 4 main arguments, app_id, version_id, entity_id and the "WordList" Object. 
I tried to create it manually like this

```
word_list = {'canonical_form': payload['canonicalForm'],
        'list': payload['syn_list']
        }
data = model.from_dict(word_list)
app_info['add_item_to_list'] = client.model.patch_closed_list(payload['app_id'], payload['version_id'], payload['cl_entity_id'], data)
```

This code gives me an error saying that it is unable to Serialize the data

Comment: Can you add some code that you have tried, so I can best help you resolve your issue?

Comment: I have updated the question with code snippet

Comment: Were you able to get this working?